# Problemas con OnActivityResult

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para el móvil y lo que intento hacer es que al sacar una foto pulsando sobre un botón la cámara se abre y que cuando le doy a aceptar a la imagen se me guarde, pero nunca se me da guardado.

Estuve depurando y lo que hace es meterse dentro de TakePicture y la cámara se enciende pero después nunca se mete en `OnActivityResult` y no se como solucionarlo.

```
private void TakeAPicture (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        try
        {
            if (PermissionManager.CheckCameraPermission(Activity))
            {


                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);


            }
            else
            {
                PermissionManager.RequestCameraPermission(Activity);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, GetString(Resource.String.toast_error_camera), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Crashes.TrackError(e);
        }


    }



    public override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != 0)
        {
            try
            {



                Bitmap bitmap = bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.PostRotate(90);
                Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, matrix, true);

                if (bmp == null)
                    return;

                Bitmap bmpResized = ImageUtils.ResizeBitmap2(bmp, 600);

                if (bmpResized == null)
                    return;

                selectedImage = bmpResized;

                vImage.SetImageBitmap(selectedImage);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, GetString(Resource.String.toast_error_camera), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
            }

            // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
            GC.Collect();

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación relacionada a [StartActivityForResult](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult/p/Android.Content.Intent/System.Int32/):

```
 StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

en realidad estas definiendo que ejecute el bloque de código cuando `resultCode` sea diferente a 0 :

```
   if (resultCode != 0)
        {
         ...
         ...
         ...
         }
```

te sugiero cambiar la lógica usando `Result.OK`:

> Result.OK : Resultado de la actividad estándar: operación exitosa.

```
   if (resultCode == Result.OK)
        {
         ...
         ...
         ...
         }else{
           Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Ocurrió un error a tomar la foto", ToastLength.Long).Show();
         }
```